# Nested Dictonary is not updating as required

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary which has sub-dictionary keys as the remaining elements of the list. To explain it in a simpler way:

Required output:

`payable = { 'A':{'B':0,'C':0},'B':{'A':0,'C':0}....}`

Output:

`payable = { 'A':{'B':0,'C':0,'A':0},'B':{'A':0,'C':0,'B':0}....}`

**I don't need the** `'A'` **sub-key under the** `'A'` **main-key. How can I fix this?**

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']  
payable = dict.fromkeys(names, {})  
for mainKey in payable.keys():
    for subKey in names:
        if(mainKey != subKey):
            payable[mainKey][subKey] = 0 
print(payable)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create using `dict.fromkeys`, all the keys are looking at the same `dict`.

Try creating `payable` with `dict` comprehension (in other words, new `dict` for each key) and it works fine:

```
names = ['A','B','C']  
payable= {k:{} for k in names}
for mainKey in payable.keys():
    for subKey in names:
        if(mainKey!=subKey):
            payable[mainKey][subKey]=0 
print(payable)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'B': 0, 'C': 0}, 'B': {'A': 0, 'C': 0}, 'C': {'A': 0, 'B': 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. Is it because of the object references in python, like the one where we use deep copy and shallow copy?something like that?

Comment: yes. Try `[id(v) for v in payable.values()]` after using `dict.fromkeys` and you can see that they all have same ids

Answer (score 2):

A simple dict comprehension like this would also work:

```
>>> names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> {x: dict.fromkeys(names[:i] + names[i+1:], 0) for i, x in enumerate(names)}
{'A': {'B': 0, 'C': 0}, 'B': {'A': 0, 'C': 0}, 'C': {'A': 0, 'B': 0}}
```

**Explanation:**

- Get every other element with list slicing: `names[:i] + names[i+1:]`
- initialize dictionary values to zero with [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)
- Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over the index and item of `names`

Additionally, we can use set difference if we don't care about key order, as [VPfb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154291/nested-dictonary-is-not-updating-as-required/58154684#comment102694161_58154684) shows in the comments:

```
>>> names = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
>>> {x: dict.fromkeys(names - {x} , 0) for x in names}
{'B': {'C': 0, 'A': 0}, 'C': {'B': 0, 'A': 0}, 'A': {'B': 0, 'C': 0}}
```

Comment: Nice. And if the order is not important, it can be even more shortened with `names` of type set: `{x: dict.fromkeys(names - {x} , 0) for x in names}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround

```
names = ['A','B','C'] 
payable = dict()
for key in names:
    tmp = dict()
    for sub in names:
        if sub == key:
          tmp[sub] = 0
    payable[key] = tmp
print(payable)
# {'A': {'A': 0}, 'B': {'B': 0}, 'C': {'C': 0}}
```